# How to tell if DirectX 9.0c is installed

Tags: directx, directx-9

This is related to this question >> [DirectX 11 is installed but programs say DirectX 9.0c is needed](https://superuser.com/questions/767482/directx-11-is-installed-but-programs-say-directx-9-0c-is-needed)

But more so that I don't get "errors" saying I don't have DirectX 9.0c installed, but I can't launch Retroarch and I'm thinking it's related to DirectX 9.0c not being installed. I get an error relating to memory that can't be written, but this could be related to other things like how I use GPU Passthrough via vt-d or Windows 10 LTSB. (Retroarch launches with the video_driver set to "gdi", but not with GL or D3D)

**So to confirm if I even have the DLL's required/installed for DirectX 9.0c installed, how can I check?**

Comment: Unrelated but retroarch launched with video_driver set to d3d11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something called the "DirectX 9.0c Control Panel" which verified the installation for me.

Couldn't find offical DL but here it is @ MajorGeeks >> http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_directx_control_panel.html

[image]